# Condition for $(1,1)$-classes on complex tori

Tags: algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry, kahler-manifolds

Let $X = V/\Lambda$ be a complex torus, where $V$ is a complex vector space and $\Lambda \subset V$ is a full-rank lattice.  We can identify the cohomology group $H^{2}(X, \mathbb{Z})$ with alternating forms $E: \Lambda \times \Lambda \to \mathbb{Z}$.  So every such form we may identify as the first Chern class of some $C^{\infty}$ complex line bundle on $X$.

Now, it seems to be well-known that $E$ is the first Chern class of a *holomorphic* line bundle if and only if $E_{\mathbb{R}} (iu, iv) = E_{\mathbb{R}}(u,v)$ for all $u,v \in V$.  Here, $E_{\mathbb{R}}: V \times V \to \mathbb{R}$ is the $\mathbb{R}$-linear extension of $E$.

Unless I'm seriously mistaken, one should then be able to show that $E_{\mathbb{R}} (iu, iv) = E_{\mathbb{R}}(u,v)$ holds if and only if the image of $E_{\mathbb{R}}$ under the Hodge decomposition lies in $H^{1,1}(X)$.  Is this true?  If so, is it straightforward to prove?  I've tried showing it directly, and failed.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but the statement that $E$ lies in $H^{1,1}(X)$ just means that it is complex linear in the first and anti-linear in the second variable. From the relation $E$ satisfies we get that $E(iu,v) = E(-u,iv) = -E(u,iv)$. This seems to imply the required statement.

Comment: @random123 It's tempting to write that, but I don't think we can.  I should have emphasized in the OP that $E_{\mathbb{R}}$ is bilinear only over $\mathbb{R}$ not $\mathbb{C}$.  Basically, it is the imaginary part of a Hermitian form on a complex vector space.

Comment: Do you mean the equalities I wrote are wrong? The elements $iu \in V$. I have not used complex linearity of $E$ anywhere in the sequence of equalities.

Comment: Okay I think I misunderstood what you said, sorry.  Why does being of (1,1) type mean you're complex linear in the first slot and antilinear in the second?  This is precisely the complex linearity issue I was worried about.  Thanks!

Comment: Some computations like these have been done in Abelian Varieties by Mumford. Perhaps Chapter 1, Section 1 titled complex tori will be of some help.